# How to debug Drupal Forms

Tags: 6, debugging

Sometime back I'd gone through a Lullabot video that showed me how to simply click a form and see all its elements using Krumo using Devel module.

But I've searched all internet I'm not able to find this feature. How do I simply click a form and see all of it's elements in Krumo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just to implement the `hook_form_alter` in a test module this way:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'taxonomy_form_term':
      dpm($form);
      break;
  }
}
```

where `$form_id` is form identifier (in the example code I captured the new taxonomy term entry form) which you can find through firebug.

Comment: Thanks but I want a tool so that I can click any form and see its arguments.

Comment: If you want to see every form you can just remove the switch from the code above, leaving only dpm($form). Of course Devel must be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Drupal For Firebug](http://drupal.org/project/drupalforfirebug) module.

Comment: Thanks but it wasn't using this module.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I touched this, but you may be referring to Devel Themer. Devel had this functionality, but it had been spun off separately to [Theme Developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer).

Comment: I've checked it it does show something in Kromo but could not verify if those data are of the clicked form...

Answer (score 1):

Krumo is a replacement for print_r() and var_dump().
Have you tried Devel + Theme Developer module? They are a must.

Krumo is included inside Devel module as stated here: http://drupal.org/project/krumo

If you have drush installed alread the commands are:

```
$ drush dl devel devel_themer
$ drush en devel devel_themer
```

Otherwise you need to download them via drupal.com and manually install and activated them.

Here is a screencast about debugging:
http://ftp.drupal.org/files/videocasts/moshe-theme-developer.mov
Good Luck!